# Is it possible to know every input and output of a Microcontrollers in Trace32?

Tags: input, output, trace, trace32, lauterbach

Is it possible to know every microcontroler in Trace32 input and output at real time ?

I would know when an external port is connecting to the microcontroler.

Comment: You might be looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_scan, the TRACE32 manual can be found here: https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/boundary_scan.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your help @dev15. But, I don't have a more simple method for know at which frequency are the external pins of mcirocontroller ? I have a power debug pro who use with jtag.

Comment: I see the jtag is the same as boudary scan. So, can i use the boundary scan or it's useless?

Comment: Depending on the frequency of the pins this might be possible, or not. If the pins are memory mapped (please check the device datasheet) you could read the values by reading the memory. Depending on your device you could use the `PER` command for this. This will open a peripheral register window. But this will only work if the pins don't change that often, for example only once per second.

Comment: I try to see pins on perf command but it doesn't work. I try to see this in GPIO.

Comment: I checked already the device datasheet and the name of the pins on the datasheet is not the same as perf command. So it's why I don't understand.